# Connecting Keycloak domain mode to a remote MariaDB

Tags: database, jboss, mariadb, keycloak

I wanted to deploy Keycloak (v 15.0.2) on the domain mode using MariaDB as an external DB.
Imagine my DB is on 10.0.0.1. I deploy my master on 10.0.0.1 as well by modifying the "KeycloakDS" datasource and the drivers in domain.xml.

I also wanted to deploy a slave on 10.0.0.2 by modifying the domain.xml and the `host-slave.xml` as the documentation of the Keycloak mentioned ([link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/15.0/server_installation/#_domain-mode)). I made the below changes on "KeycloakDS" in domain.xml:

```xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS"> 
    <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://10.0.0.1:3306/keycloak</connection-url> 
    <driver>mariadb</driver> 
    <security>
        <user-name>myuser</user-name>
        <password>mypassword</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Note telnet on 3306 from 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.1 is Ok.

After the above changes, I wanted to deploy the slave on 10.0.0.2 but keep facing the error below:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection refused: connect
```

Also note that the sceneio works properly for the standalone-ha mode by making the same changes in `standalone-ha.xml`.

I followed this link: [Installing and Configuring Keycloak - Domain Clustered Deployment](https://samer-younes.medium.com/installing-and-configuring-keycloak-domain-clustered-deployment-fe941146d3c4)
Does anyone have any suggestion that how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the datasource on both

`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:6.0">` in `/domain.xml` file.

when I was reviewing the file i found there two occurrences of that subsystem.